# Can this be done in a single SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `lists` with columns `list_id`, `name`, etc. I have another table `members` with columns `user_id` and `list_id` (with a unique index on the pair (user,list)).

Now, I want to generate a three-column output: `list_id`, `name`, `membership` where membership is `0` or `1` depending on whether or not the current user is member of the list (i.e. there is an entry for that user on that list). If I do

```
SELECT 
  list_id, name, 1 
FROM 
  lists 
  LEFT JOIN members ON (lists.list_id = members.list_id AND members.user_id=2)
```

I will get the correct 1-rows for user 2, but the 0-rows will simply be gone. Is there a nice way to obtain my desired effect with a single MySQL query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT list_id, name, (m.list_id is not null) as MemberOnList
FROM lists l LEFT JOIN
     members m
     ON l.list_id = m.list_id and
        m.member_id = @CURRENTUSER;
```

Comment: Ah, that was part of the syntax that I didn't know. Thanks!